# Azure Data Factory - Use system variable in Dynamic Content

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to use system variable '@pipeline().TriggerTime' in a dynamic content field.

I have a 'Copy Data' activity which has a sink dataset to a folder.

[image]

Inside this Sink dataset, I try to set the filepath to

```
@concat('Trigger_',formatDateTime(@pipeline().TriggerTime, 'ddMMyyyyHHmmss'), '.trg')
```

[image]

But I get the following error message.

[image]

The activity is contained in an 'If Condition' block which itself is contained in a 'ForEach' but this variable should be global in the pipeline so I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The @ symbol only appears once at the beginning of the function. Change "@pipeline" to just "pipeline" and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joel comments,just change "@pipeline" to "pipeline".

```
@concat('Trigger_',formatDateTime(pipeline().TriggerTime, 'ddMMyyyyHHmmss'), '.trg')
```

If you want to use multiple functions,you just add @ at the beginning.
If you want to get the string of functions,you need to add double @,such as "Answer is: @@{pipeline().parameters.myNumber}" return the string Answer is: @{pipeline().parameters.myNumber}.

More detail,you can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#expressions).